# how to transpose table in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular6, angular7

what ever the data displaying in column it should display in row 
how to transpose table i.e row to column and column to row in angular 
For example I have an table like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

And I want it like this:

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

transpose row to column and column to row

Comment: You should flesh out the example a bit, it's hard to follow with just empty cells.

Comment: can you please post your `angular6` code to generate table.

Comment: div class = "col-md-8"  style="margin:10px 15em;">
<div >
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tbody >
      <tr *ngFor="let key of objectKeys(contents)">
        <td *ngFor="let sKey of objectKeys(contents[key])">{{contents[key][sKey]}}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
  </div>

</div>